# Generate a Refresh Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a work flow that works like this:

1. User on mobile device uses a login with Google work flow and gets a token back.
2. User passes id_token to my WebAPI endpoint.
3. WebAPI validates the token via google endpoint, saves user data to a database, and generates refresh and access tokens.
4. When user needs to use my api, they provide access token via bearer authentication header.
5. If access token has expired or is going to expired, app provides refresh token and receives a new access token.

This is a pretty standard workflow I believe.  Where I am currently stuck is how to generate a secure refresh token.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and would love a little direction in how to generate this refresh token.  I'm actually having a hard time even finding the refresh token format as well.  I can generate an access token fairly easily using the JwtSecurityToken, JwtSecurityTokenHandler and SecurityTokenDescriptor classes.

Could this be as simple as using a symmetrical encryption algorithm on a json string and sending it over the wire?

Comment: Are you using their SDK or doing this by hand? I would suggest using their SDK as they tend to handle all that under the covers for you. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/identitytoolkit/v3

Comment: I am past the Google part of this.  I'm essentially trying to issue my own refresh token but I can't seem to find what it is comprised of.  All of my search results tell what it is used for and what the access token is comprised of, but precious little about what makes up the refresh token.